# Featured post showing in posts but not on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on my first WordPress theme using underscores, I have already added the 'featured post' code in the functions. Php and called it from the 'loop' in the 'single. Php. But I ended up getting featured images only when I view a post, and not on the homepage, I will appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks! 
This is in my functions.php file

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 590, 180); // 590 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, resize mode
```

this is the code in my single.php

```
<?php   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); endif;
```

Sorry, it's my first time here...

Comment: Please include examples of your code so the community can better evaluate this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in template-parts/content.php, include

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); endif;
```

Like this:

```
        <?php

            if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); endif;

            the_content( sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
                wp_kses( __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', '_s' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
            ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', '_s' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow,  thanks a lot, it was supposed to be in content.php all along. I appreciate.